# How to remove all device icons from Unity launcher in 13.10?

Tags: unity, launcher, 13.10

How to remove all drives icons from Unity launcher in 13.10?

Old trick with `dconf-editor` does not work anymore. I can remove any entry from `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher.favorites`, but not `unity://devices` or `unity://running-apps`.

If I do delete them then these entries are automatically added back to the favorites.

Comment: as explain here the solution is not persistent it may be a bug ?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/352790/how-can-i-hide-mounted-drives-from-unity-launcher