# How can I remove launcher drive icons on 14.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, 14.04

Non of the solutions work from [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-can-i-remove-launcher-drive-icons). Do someone have any solution for the new, 14.04 release?

[Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361904/how-to-remove-all-device-icons-from-unity-launcher-in-13-10)